# Confusion of codes in the django views part

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=category_choices, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=label_choices, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })



class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"




class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username




 def add_to_cart(request, slug):
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
        order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
            item=item,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False
        )
        order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
        if order_qs.exists():
            order = order_qs[0]
            # check if the order item is in the order
            if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
                order_item.quantity += 1
                order_item.save()
            else:
                order.items.add(order_item)
        else:
            ordered_date = timezone.now()
            order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
            order.items.add(order_item)
        return redirect("product",slug=slug)
```

i am learning it. here above i am trying to adding products to the cart. first i am taking the objects of particular slug,and then store inside OrderItem class.but i am confuse how :                                                     if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists(): this line work. what is the function of double undescore before slug?

Answer (score 0):

It's a lookup that spans a relation. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) is top-notch on this.

Basically, in this case, you could imagine a `.` where the double underscore is.

```
order.items.filter(item__slug=some_slug)
```

would be something like (but don't do this, it's slow!)

```
[item for item in order.items if item.slug == some_slug]
```

Comment: ya ya i got it and what is the purpose of making order=False